# Is it okay to pass MPI_Request by value?

Tags: mpi

Is it okay to pass MPI_Request by value, or to make a copy of it? In a function like MPI_Test, why is the MPI_Request passed as a pointer, as opposed to just a pass-by-value? MPI_Request isn't modified within MPI_Test, is it? It's only 8 bytes in size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_Request` is an opaque type and you should not assume anything about its size (since it might differ between various MPI libraries).
i believe `MPI_Request` can be modified by `MPI_Test` (for example, `MPI_Test`) might mark the request as completed when appropriate.